# How to add images in the folder in python

Tags: python

How I can save images in a folder? The folder comes from another user, where the user wants to save that images.
Where to write folder name which is got from the user?

Comment: What are the images. Do you have the path of the images? Also, what did you write

Comment: Please start here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how do I use user input and put it in path

Comment: It is important to be clear about your problem. Try explaining everything vividly and preferably use examples, such as code, pseudo-code, images, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing OpenCV using, `pip install opencv-python` in any command line.
Then, use the code snippet below.

```py
import cv2
from os import path

def saveImage(image):
    myImage
    address = input('Please enter your address here:')
    imgSaveDir = path.join(address, 'yourImagesName')
    cv2.imwrite(imgSaveDir , image)
```

Using this function, you'll be able to save your image in any directory you put as your input.

Comment: how do I take user input and put it in the path like if  I code "C:\Users\Abaid\Desktop\face\train-images\5\image%04i.jpg" like this the user should just enter a digit it will automatically at the place of 5

Comment: `address = input('Please enter your address here:')`
    `imgSaveDir = path.join(address, 'yourImagesName')` these two line of code is for taking your path as user input and combining it with your current image name.

Comment: how do I take user input and put it in the path like if I code "C:\Users\Abaid\Desktop\face\train-images\5\image%04i.jpg" like this the user should just enter a digit it will automatically at the place of 5 only

Comment: You can use a relative path, `path.join('.', folderNumberFromInput,'file.img')`. Keep in mind that your path __should__ exist, otherwise it'll not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take the input from user
Eg. Id=input("input your id")
And if you want to use this id in your path
Just add it like
r"C\user\abaid\desktop{Id}